Duplicated call of onConnected() in Spring when calling io() socket.io-client function
I'm trying to set up a Socket.IO server with Spring boot, which also serves as an API for my application. I have an Angular frontend that looks like this:
The problem is when I call my service to connect, it calls the onConnected method of my Spring back twice. I tried to simplify it by removing, for example, the call to the client.joinRoom(sessionCode) method but the logs remain the same.
Could I have an error in my client or in the way I set up my socket.io server?
I tried to add the reconnect event to my client, and to remove the event 'connect'.
I tried using a node server, it works perfectly, but it is too complexe to communicate between 3 applications, i want to make it in Spring.
Component :
import { Component, HostBinding, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from "@angular/forms";
import { GameSessionService } from "../../services/game-session.service";
import { SocketService } from "../../services/socket.service";
import { GameSessionI } from "../../interfaces/GameSessionI";



@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-game',
  templateUrl: './create-game.page.html',
  styleUrl: './create-game.page.scss',
})
export class CreateGamePage implements OnInit {
  createGameForm: FormGroup;

  @HostBinding('class') class = 'tw-my-auto';
  colorPrimaryString: string = 'primary';
  colorGreyString: string = 'grey';
  username: string = '';

  constructor(fb: FormBuilder, private readonly gameSessionService : GameSessionService, private readonly socketService: SocketService) {
    this.createGameForm = fb.group({
      username: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  onSubmit() {
    this.gameSessionService.createGameSession(
      this.createGameForm.value.username,
    ).subscribe(
      (gameSession: GameSessionI) => {
        console.log(gameSession);
        this.socketService.connect(gameSession.code, gameSession.owner.id, gameSession.owner.name);
      },
    );
  }

  backButton(){
    this.socketService.disconnect();
  }
}

Service :
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';
import { LaunchSessionDTO } from '../model/socket/LaunchSessionDTO';
import { GameSessionService } from './game-session.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class SocketService {
  socket: any;

  constructor(private readonly gameSessionService: GameSessionService) {
    
  }

  connect(sessionCode: string, userId: number, userName: string) {
    console.log(this.socket);
    if (!this.socket) {
      this.socket = io('http://localhost:9092', {
        transports: ['websocket'], // Specify transport for compatibility
        query: { sessionCode, userId, userName }, // Include handshake data
      });

      this.socket.on('connect', () => {
        console.log('Connected to socket server');
      });
      
      this.socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('Disconnected from socket server');
      });
    }
  }

  public launchSession(launchSessionDTO: LaunchSessionDTO) {
    this.socket.emit('launch_session', launchSessionDTO);
  }

  disconnect() {
    if (this.socket) {
      this.socket.disconnect();
    }
  }
}

package com.miage.beeramideback.socket.gamesession;

// imports

@Component
public final class GameSessionSocketModule {
    private final GameSessionBasicEventSocketService gameSessionSocketService;
    private final GameSessionService gameSessionService;
    private final GameSessionManagementService gameSessionManagementService;
    private final SocketIOServer server;
    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GameSessionManagementServiceImpl.class);

    //Constructeur de la classe GameSessionSocketModule
    public GameSessionSocketModule(SocketIOServer server, GameSessionSocketServiceImpl gameSessionSocketServiceImpl, GameSessionManagementServiceImpl gameSessionManagementServiceImpl, GameSessionService gameSessionService) {
        this.server = server;
        this.gameSessionSocketService = gameSessionSocketServiceImpl;
        this.gameSessionManagementService = gameSessionManagementServiceImpl;
        this.gameSessionService = gameSessionService;
        //Ajout de Listener d'événements sur les parties en cours (réagit aux actions des clients connectés au serveur via le socket)
        server.addConnectListener(this.onConnected());
        server.addDisconnectListener(this.onDisconnected());
    }

    //Détecteur de l'événement de connection d'un joueur à la session
    private ConnectListener onConnected() {
        return (client) -> {
            final var params = client.getHandshakeData().getUrlParams();
            final String sessionCode = params.get("sessionCode").stream().collect(Collectors.joining());
            final Long userId = Long.parseLong(params.get("userId").stream().collect(Collectors.joining()));
            final String userName = params.get("userName").stream().collect(Collectors.joining());
            log.info("Socket connecting '{}'  ", client.getSessionId().toString());
        };
    }



    //Détecteur de l'événement de déconnection d'un joueur à la session
    private DisconnectListener onDisconnected() {
        return client -> {
            final var params = client.getHandshakeData().getUrlParams();
            final Long userId = Long.parseLong(params.get("userId").stream().collect(Collectors.joining()));
            final String sessionCode = client.getHandshakeData().getSingleUrlParam("sessionCode");
            final String userName = params.get("userName").stream().collect(Collectors.joining());
            log.info("Client '{}'' - disconnected from socket", client.getSessionId().toString());
        };
    }
}

Here are the logs from spring when calling connect on front :
logs

It seems it is a bug in the library, a work around solution is don't use the default namespace ("/") and use another one, like:
SocketIONamespace agentsNamespace = socketIOServer.addNamespace("/agents");

And on the client side, use this url:
localhost:8090/agents

